# smarty v3, get value from smarty

Tags: smarty, smarty3

how get variable from smarty v3?
With Smarty v2 i use this function: get_template_vars, but in v3 this no't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They removed the underscores and went camelCase in version 3: [`getTemplateVars()`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl)